# Replace values in data frame based on other data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

In the below example, `userids` is my reference data frame and `userdata` is the data frame where the replacements should take place.

```
> userids <- data.frame(USER=c('Ann','Jim','Lee','Bob'),ID=c(1,2,3,4))
> userids
  USER ID
1  Ann  1
2  Jim  2
3  Lee  3
4  Bob  4

> userdata <- data.frame(INFO=c('foo','bar','foo','bar'), ID=c('Bob','Jim','Ann','Lee'),AGE=c('43','33','53','26'), FRIENDID=c('Ann',NA,'Lee','Jim'))
> userdata
  INFO  ID AGE FRIENDID
1  foo Bob  43      Ann
2  bar Jim  33       NA
3  foo Ann  53      Lee
4  bar Lee  26      Jim
```

How do I replace ID and FRIENDID in `userdata` with the ID corresponding to USER in `userids`?

The desired output:

```
  INFO  ID AGE FRIENDID
1  foo   4  43        1
2  bar   2  33       NA
3  foo   1  53        3
4  bar   3  26        2
```

Comment: What do you mean by "correct"?  Do you want to match `userids$USER` to `userdata$ID`?

Comment: I guess `correct`should be `corresponding`.

Comment: @Robert, it'd help to have the desired output (to avoid these confusions, for the next time).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `match`:

```
userdata$ID <- userids$ID[match(userdata$ID, userids$USER)]
userdata$FRIENDID <- userids$ID[match(userdata$FRIENDID, userids$USER)]
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a possibility:

```
library(qdap)
userdata$FRIENDID <- lookup(userdata$FRIENDID, userids)
userdata$ID <- lookup(userdata$ID, userids)
```

or to win the one line prize:

```
userdata[, c(2, 4)] <- lapply(userdata[, c(2, 4)], lookup, key.match=userids)
```

Comment: `qdap` looks pretty great, but I'm not seeing it in my repositories.

Comment: Not sure why.  Maybe it's because it's a newer release.  Try `install.packages("qdap")` or you could use: `library(devtools)`
`install_github("qdap", "trinker")` for the devel. version.

Comment: Failed. `ERROR: dependency 'openNLP' is not available for package 'qdap'`

Comment: What OS are you using?  If mac you have to compile from source.  See this for details: http://trinker.github.com/qdap_install/installation

Comment: Mac OSX 10.5.8 with RStudio 2.15.2

Comment: @TylerRinker this returns only friends id. Matbe you need to call it twice.

Comment: @agstudy.  Missed that.  You're correct.  I edited to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Here a try using `sqldf` to get the result as a multiple join on differents columns.

```
  library(sqldf)
  sqldf('SELECT d.INFO,d.AGE,i1.ID ,i2.ID FRIENDID
       FROM 
       userdata d
       INNER JOIN 
       userids i1 ON (i1.USER=d.FRIENDID)
       INNER JOIN
        userids i2 ON (i2.USER=d.ID)')

 INFO AGE ID FRIENDID
1  foo  43  1        4
2  foo  53  3        1
3  bar  26  2        3
```

But this this removes NA lines! maybe someone can suggest me something on how to deal with NA!

**EDIT**

Thanks to  G. Grothendieck comment, replacing the INNER by LEFT we get the result.

```
 sqldf('SELECT d.INFO,d.AGE,i1.ID ,i2.ID FRIENDID
        FROM 
        userdata d
        LEFT JOIN 
        userids i1 ON (i1.USER=d.FRIENDID)
        LEFT JOIN
         userids i2 ON (i2.USER=d.ID)')
INFO AGE ID FRIENDID
1  foo  43  1        4
2  bar  33 NA        2
3  foo  53  3        1
4  bar  26  2        3
```

Comment: Regarding your question replace the two instances of `INNER` with `LEFT` .

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution, which will also work on datasets with multiple records of each ID, though we will need to coerce the ID and FRIENDID variables to character first:

```
> userdata$ID <- sapply(userdata$ID, function(x){gsub(x, userids[userids$USER==x, 2], x)})
> userdata$FRIENDID <- sapply(userdata$FRIENDID, function(x){gsub(x, userids[userids$USER==x, 2], x)})
```