# R - Replace column values by multiple pairs

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to replace all values in a column by pairs provided from a data frame. I've come up with a solution in a for loop, which is too slow given the amount of data I have. I haven't come up with a vectorized solution so far.

What I want to achieve is the following:

```
id_name = tibble(Id = c(1,2), Names = c("abc","xyz"))
dt = tibble(ID = rep(c(1,2), each = 5), val = 1:10)

for(i in 1:nrow(dt)){
    replace_value = id_name$Names[which(dt$ID[i] == id_name$Id) ]
    dt$ID[i] = replace_value
}
```

I tried `recode()`, however as my final numer of replacement pairs may be greater than 20, I am not willing to type every replacement pair in the fuction, like `` recode(dt, `1`="xyz") ``.

However it seems not to be possible to put recode in a loop,
as this doesnt work (I also tried transforming with `as.character()` before:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(id_name)){
  dt$ID = recode(dt$ID, id_name$Id[i] = id_name$Names[i])
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand what you are doing but `$` notation does something completely different in tibbles than it does in data frames.  For complex things you maybe be better off sticking with data frames.

Comment: Try `dt$ID <- id_name$Names[match(dt$ID, id_name$Id)]`.

Comment: You have tagged this question `dplyr`. My solution above and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15069984/replace-values-in-data-frame-based-on-other-data-frame-in-r) are base R. Do you really need a `dplyr` solution?